# host command resolves IP address but gives host not found error

Tags: linux, domain-name-system

I am having issues with one of the EC2 instance where I have application dying because it is not able to resolve other systems in the same VPC.

When I run `host ip-10.123.22.100` command on a server, I get this response back.

```
ip-10.123.22.100.corp.domain.com has address 10.123.22.100
Host ip-10.123.22.100.corp.domain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
Host ip-10.123.22.100.corp.domain.com not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

When I do `ping 10.123.22.100`, I get the response back.

I am suspecting there is something screwy going on with DNS system but I am struggling to figure out what could cause this.

Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: What is the output of `dig ip-10.123.22.100.corp.domain.com`?

Comment: @fpmurphy: I do not have dig output but ping works fine. Also noticed that there is an entry as `nameserver 127.0.0.1` in /etc/resolv.conf file. Could that potentially be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this might be due to `host` also looking up MX records in addition to an A and AAAA records.

from the `host` man page:

> The -t option is used to select the query type. type can be any
> recognized query type: CNAME, NS, SOA, SIG, KEY, AXFR, etc. When no
> query type is specified, host automatically selects an appropriate
> query type. **By default, it looks for A, AAAA, and MX records**, but if
> the -C option was given, queries will be made for SOA records, and if
> name is a dotted-decimal IPv4 address or colon-delimited IPv6 address,
> host will query for PTR records. If a query type of IXFR is chosen the
> starting serial number can be specified by appending an equal followed
> by the starting serial number (e.g. -t IXFR=12345678).

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/host

Or more simply:

> The host command requests three records:
>
> - A Record
> - AAAA Record
> - MX Record
>
> If there is no AAAA record and IPv6 NoError Response is not enabled
> you will see one of this error lines. The second error line with "not
> found: 3(NXDOMAIN)" will show if there is no MX record.

- https://support.f5.com/csp/article/K96094134

---

So it looks like your host doesn't have associated MX or AAAA dns records?

This is why [@fpmurphy](https://serverfault.com/users/11318/fpmurphy) is asking what the output of the dig command is, since `dig` by default only looks for the `A` record:

> *type* indicates what type of query is required - ANY, A, MX, SIG, etc. type can be any valid query type. **If no type argument is
> supplied, dig will perform a lookup for an A record.**

- https://linux.die.net/man/1/dig